# Invalid syntax error using format with a string in Python 3 and Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

The code:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy.solvers import *
from sympy import *
from matplotlib import rcParams


rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\usepackage{amsthm}', '\usepackage{amsmath}', '\usepackage{amssymb}',
'\usepackage{amsfonts}', '\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}', '\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}'


f = lambda x: x ** 2 + 1
#f = lambda x: np.sin(x) / x

x = Symbol('x')
solucion = solve(x**2+1, x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-6.0, 6.0, 1000)
ax.axis([x[0] - 0.5, x[-1] + 0.5, x[0] - 0.5, x[-1] + 0.5])
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top']
ax.spines['left']
ax.spines['bottom']
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.grid('on')
ticks = []
for i in range(int(x[0]), int(x[-1] + 1), 1):
    ticks.append(i)
ticks.remove(0)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)

ax.plot(x, f(x), 'b-', lw=1.5)
ax.legend([r'$f(x)=x^2-1$'], loc='lower right')

text_sol = ''
if solucion == []:
    text_sol = r'$No\; hay\; soluciones $'
else:
    for i, value in enumerate(solucion):
        text_sol += ur'$Solución \; {}\; :\; {}\\$'.format(i, value)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle='round', fc='white', ec='black', lw=2)
t = ax.text(-5.5, -5, text_sol, ha='left', va='center', size=15,
            bbox=bbox_props)

plt.show()
```

This code works fine with Python 2.7 but with Python 3.3.2 is bad:

```
python3 funcion_pol2.py
  File "funcion_pol2.py", line 51
    text_sol += ur'$Solución \; {}\; :\; {}\\$'.format(i, value)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks!

Comment: why someone marked it off-topic!!??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan there's no telling. But while I think this is a good question, it has nothing to do with the matplotlib library. So the problem could be trimmed down significantly and the matplotlib tag removed in the OP were so inclined.

Comment: @PaulH yes you are correct, I like this question because I didn't know this difference between Python2.X and 3.X

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `u'...'` syntax for string literal was removed in Python 3.0

- [All strings are unicode strings in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

> String literals no longer support a leading `u` or `U`.

So, you can simply drop the `u'...'` in Python 3:

```
r'$Solución \; {}\; :\; {}\\$'.format(i, value)
```

---

**Note:** The `u'...'` syntax has been [re-introduced in Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html)(thanks to @Bakuriu for pointing that out).

And the new re-introduced [string-prefix syntax](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) looks like this:

```
stringprefix    ::=  "r" | "u" | "R" | "U"
```

Python 2 [string-prefix syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
stringprefix    ::=  "r" | "u" | "ur" | "R" | "U" | "UR" | "Ur" | "uR"
                     | "b" | "B" | "br" | "Br" | "bR" | "BR"
```

Comment: @Bakuriu Didn't know that, just tried that on Python 3.3 but it doesn't seem to work with `ur`.

Comment: Uhm. seems like the backported the `u` prefix but not `ur`... pretty strange.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using Python 3.3, the problem is **not** that you have a `u` before the string literal.  Instead, the problem is that you are placing `ur` before it:

```
>>> # Python 3.3.2 interpreter
>>> u'a'
'a'
>>> ur'a'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ur'a'
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

This behavior is explained in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Given that Python 2.x’s raw unicode literals behave differently than
>   Python 3.x’s the 'ur' syntax is not supported.
>
> ...
>
> New in version 3.3: Support for the unicode legacy literal (u'value') was 
>   reintroduced to simplify the maintenance of dual Python
>   2.x and 3.x codebases. See [PEP 414](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/) for more information.

---

Since all strings in Python 3.x are unicode, you can fix the problem by simply removing the `u`:

```
r'$Solución \; {}\; :\; {}\\$'.format(i, value)
```

Comment: so, i have got a new error if I put this change  python3 funcion_pol2.py
  File "funcion_pol2.py", line 14
    rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = '\usepackage{amsthm}', '\usepackage{amsmath}', '\usepackage{amssymb}',
                                     ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: ok i've mended the error using '\\usepackage{amsthm}' opposite to '\usepackage{amsthm}'.